# Can Spring Batch Admin automatically launch a job on startup?

Tags: spring-batch-admin

I have placed my job xml in the spring/batch/jobs directory and can launch the job from the console by clicking on the launch button.  I would like to have the job launch whenever the Tomcat instance where the admin console is deployed starts up.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To launch a job on startup, create a bean that launches a job in it's constructor or init method.  From there, if you configure it as a bean in Spring, by default it will be a singleton, created once, and therefore launch the job as soon as the context is ready.